# How to get off the floor by half the height of View using a snapkit

Tags: swift, uikit, snapkit

[image]

'UIView' is displayed using the snapkit (assuming 200 heights)

Use "equalToSuperview" to secure it to the floor

I want to lower the Y axis of the UI view to half the height.

```
self.tempView.snp.makeConstraints {
    $0.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(-50)
    $0.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(50)
    $0.height.equalTo(self.tempView.snp.width)
    $0.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(self.tempView.snp.height / 2)
}
```

Comment: I would just pin centerY anchor of your view to the bottom anchor of parent view. There is no need to play with offset like you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the bottom of `tempView` to be `superview.bottom + tempView.height / 2`. Notice that this is the same as saying that the centre Y of `tempView` should be equal to the bottom of its superview.

```
make.centerY.equalTo(yourSuperview.snp.bottom)
```

If the offset is another ratio of the height, like 1/3 of the height, then I would use another view, placed at the bottom of the superview, to help:

```
// anotherView should be added as a sibling of tempView
anotherView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.top.equalTo(yourSuperview.snp.bottom)
    make.horizontalEdges.equalToSuperview()
    make.height.equalTo(tempView.snp.height).dividedBy(3)
}

tempView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    // ...
    make.bottom.equalTo(anotherView.snp.bottom)
}
```